# Height of button doesn't adjust

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a vertical stackview containing multiple horizontal stackviews each containing an imageview and a button.
I have put a contraint on the vertical stackview fixating its width
now, i want the buttons to line-break, if necessary, therefore i linked the vertical stackview to an outlet called `menu` and put the following code in my viewcontroller:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews) {
    let subs = menu.subviews
    for sub in subs {
        let button = (sub as! UIStackView).subviews[1] as! UIButton
        button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    }
}
```

it works, except the buttons height doesn't adjust therefore if i set a background to the button the text is partly outside of the background and overlaps with the text of the above or beneath button. What am i missing?

here is my storyboard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="13771" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="k7d-Lf-DdI">
    <device id="ipad9_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="13772"/>
        <capability name="Aspect ratio constraints" minToolsVersion="5.1"/>
        <capability name="Constraints with non-1.0 multipliers" minToolsVersion="5.1"/>
        <capability name="Named colors" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>

        <!--Main Menu View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="xho-sd-pLC">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="k7d-Lf-DdI" customClass="MainMenuViewController" customModule="ACONEXT_Messe" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="XV4-1t-imf">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="768" height="1024"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="Bild1" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="xDe-WB-MVY">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="20" width="768" height="825.5"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="xDe-WB-MVY" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="780:838" id="gO5-cK-oIL"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </imageView>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="gAb-Td-Uze">
                                <rect key="frame" x="388" y="248" width="350" height="528"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="ZN1-hX-aTU">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="350" height="48"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="enumT" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="klr-J5-Gwl">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="42" height="48"/>
                                            </imageView>
                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="M0z-rb-D7a">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="42" y="0.0" width="308" height="48"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="30"/>
                                                <state key="normal" title="some text">
                                                    <color key="titleColor" name="BackGroundColor"/>
                                                </state>
                                            </button>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="8KN-i0-y1t">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="48" width="350" height="48"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="enumT" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="AJh-Xg-4aR">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="42" height="48"/>
                                            </imageView>
                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="XQt-BQ-Wjs">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="42" y="0.0" width="308" height="48"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="30"/>
                                                <state key="normal" title="some text">
                                                    <color key="titleColor" name="BackGroundColor"/>
                                                </state>
                                            </button>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Z1F-tk-lEr">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="96" width="350" height="48"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="enumT" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="1mi-Mg-iZe">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="42" height="48"/>
                                            </imageView>
                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="SId-mO-ZuF">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="42" y="0.0" width="308" height="48"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="30"/>
                                                <state key="normal" title="some text">
                                                    <color key="titleColor" name="BackGroundColor"/>
                                                </state>
                                            </button>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="kjk-aA-ps2">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="144" width="350" height="48"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="enumT" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="vLW-Jr-Qu6">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="42" height="48"/>
                                            </imageView>
                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="5vX-Ay-OBz">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="42" y="0.0" width="308" height="48"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="30"/>
                                                <state key="normal" title="some text">
                                                    <color key="titleColor" name="BackGroundColor"/>
                                                </state>
                                            </button>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="hSl-PB-uUB">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="192" width="350" height="48"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="enumT" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="GAP-AZ-6cQ">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="42" height="48"/>
                                            </imageView>
                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="K4S-kp-XzA">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="42" y="0.0" width="308" height="48"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="30"/>
                                                <state key="normal" title="some text">
                                                    <color key="titleColor" name="BackGroundColor"/>
                                                </state>
                                            </button>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Z7X-hV-fRA">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="240" width="350" height="48"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="enumT" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Msw-Xl-yXL">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="42" height="48"/>
                                            </imageView>
                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="hiS-tx-7tX">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="42" y="0.0" width="308" height="48"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="30"/>
                                                <state key="normal" title="some text">
                                                    <color key="titleColor" name="BackGroundColor"/>
                                                </state>
                                            </button>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="3QD-df-LPX">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="288" width="350" height="48"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="enumT" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Kbi-JW-PB5">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="42" height="48"/>
                                            </imageView>
                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="uLj-Yf-S4d">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="42" y="0.0" width="308" height="48"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="30"/>
                                                <state key="normal" title="some text">
                                                    <color key="titleColor" name="BackGroundColor"/>
                                                </state>
                                            </button>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="k7n-mH-Vcq">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="336" width="350" height="48"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="enumT" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="2Ye-AN-YHI">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="42" height="48"/>
                                            </imageView>
                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="tSL-1I-r3q">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="42" y="0.0" width="308" height="48"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="30"/>
                                                <state key="normal" title="some text">
                                                    <color key="titleColor" name="BackGroundColor"/>
                                                </state>
                                            </button>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="fVp-Bm-ZDd">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="384" width="350" height="48"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="enumT" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="DZR-7L-3aa">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="42" height="48"/>
                                            </imageView>
                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="rzn-fF-D48">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="42" y="0.0" width="308" height="48"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.1843137255" blue="0.21960784310000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="30"/>
                                                <state key="normal" title="some text">
                                                    <color key="titleColor" name="BackGroundColor"/>
                                                </state>
                                            </button>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="g7p-aG-xIi">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="432" width="350" height="48"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="enumT" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="hUE-I9-mdj">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="42" height="48"/>
                                            </imageView>
                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Zij-HM-fWo">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="42" y="0.0" width="308" height="48"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="30"/>
                                                <state key="normal" title="some text">
                                                    <color key="titleColor" name="BackGroundColor"/>
                                                </state>
                                            </button>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="X9r-t4-HaO">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="480" width="350" height="48"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="enumT" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="EBB-JR-5ZH">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="42" height="48"/>
                                            </imageView>
                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Wst-YV-9xu">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="42" y="0.0" width="308" height="48"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="30"/>
                                                <state key="normal" title="some text">
                                                    <color key="titleColor" name="BackGroundColor"/>
                                                </state>
                                            </button>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                </subviews>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="350" id="54x-qf-5f6"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </stackView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="xDe-WB-MVY" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="dSq-dG-pDQ" secondAttribute="top" id="7eR-ko-kMe"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="dSq-dG-pDQ" firstAttribute="trailing" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="xDe-WB-MVY" secondAttribute="trailing" id="Ciq-JE-Xnu"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="dSq-dG-pDQ" firstAttribute="bottom" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="xDe-WB-MVY" secondAttribute="bottom" id="EVt-RQ-2CA"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="xDe-WB-MVY" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="dSq-dG-pDQ" secondAttribute="leading" id="I4p-vc-AYQ"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="gAb-Td-Uze" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="XV4-1t-imf" secondAttribute="centerY" id="PPK-aW-84x"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="gAb-Td-Uze" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="30" id="cMV-ov-cBP"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="dSq-dG-pDQ"/>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="menu" destination="gAb-Td-Uze" id="0Xl-8M-JYF"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="XaN-tK-Fs5" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="848" y="15"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <image name="Bild1" width="780" height="838"/>
        <image name="enumT" width="42" height="29"/>
        <namedColor name="BackGroundColor">
            <color red="0.14117647059999999" green="0.1529411765" blue="0.18823529410000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </namedColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

as u propably noticed, i'm using SWIFT

Comment: Put `button.sizeToFit()`

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: How do you add the stack view? Which constraints does it have?

Comment: see yourself, I added the storyboard. The vertical one has a fixed trailing space to superview, is centered vertically and as said has a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't apply values to view properties in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` which can change the layout. This may lead to infinite loops. You should set it in `viewDidLoad` or in your storyboard. There's no reason to do it like this.

Since you should set the *Vertical Content Compression Resistance Priority*  of the button to *Required (1000)* in the size inspector of the button. This forces Autolayout to use a height for the button into which the text will fit completely. You should also set the *Line Break* to *Word Wrap* and limit the left and the right edge of the button to the stack view.

Comment: Setting line break to Word Wrap?  Isn't that exactly what I do in the code above? What do mean with "limit the left and right edge"? The button is contained in a horizontal StackView, therefore leading and trailing constraints have no effect, anyway, there is an image before it. i set the priority. it had no effect

Comment: @Ginso89: Reading the XML of a storyboard is very hard to understand. You should extend your post with appropriate images. However, the priority will take effect, if the button has no chance to increase into horizontal directions and if there are no conflicts. When you set all properties in your storyboard, you can see the effects and Interface Builder will give you helpful hints for conflicts.